# Why is the quality of the images so different?

Tags: graphics, lyx, resolution

The quality of many of my images is recognisable worse when exporting (in LuaTex). The image how I see it in Lyx:

[image: Lyx]

and how it is in the pdf-file:

[image: pdf]

Comment: quality of vector images (pdf) is better from rasterised (png, jpeg).

Comment: So the quality is just bad in the LyX preview window but good in the final PDF inside the PDF viewer? In that case @Zarko might be right, that LyX displayes the PDF as raster image with a lower resolution. You might be able to change that resolution using some LyX settings.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, I'm not very familiar with LyX, so I don't know, if it allow to adjust its way of (on-line) showing of writing documents. From wiki, where is stated: "LyX ... which follow the WYSIWYG ("what you see is what you get") paradigm, LyX has a WYSIWYM ("what you see is what you mean") approach, where what shows up on the screen is only an approximation of what will show up on the page." i conclude that printed mateerila or showed in pdf previewer should looks better. BTW, showed images are to small that the differences would be easy visible.

Comment: It's because in Lyx the images are shown bigger in the preview. When compiling the images are resized to fit within your pdf document. Raster images that contain lines and text are getting worse, when resized. If you're not familiar with raster and vector differences, read something about it on the web. If possible try to export your graphs to a vector format like .svg, .eps or directly .pdf and use this.